# How to exclude long protein sequences with FASTA format from my protein list

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta

I have a file that includes many protein sequences from different strains of a virus with a [FASTA](http://genetics.bwh.harvard.edu/pph/FASTA.html) format. I want to exclude the sequences which are too long in comparison to other sequences.
Can I use [Seqkit](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/) grep to exclude them? The average length of proteins is 565 amino acids.
I searched on the man-page of Seqkit but couldn't find a solution for that.
Is there any alternative way to solve this problem?

I hope that I described the problem clearly.

Comment: You may be interested in this other stackexchange site, dedicated to bioinformatics: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ Also, do you have a precise idea about what you mean by "too long in comparison to other sequences"?

Comment: Use `seqtk seq` to convert multi-line fasta to single-line fasta sequence, pipe to `paste` to get 1 fasta record per line, use `perl` or `awk` to select records by the length of the last field (sequence), `tr` to convert back to proper fasta. For example, `echo ">seq1\nACGT\n>seq2\nACGT\nA" | seqtk seq -L0 | paste - - | perl -lane 'print if length( $F[1] ) <= 4; ' | tr '\t' '\n'` . You can install `seqtk`, for example, using `conda`, e.g, `conda install seqtk`. Type `seqtk seq` for help on the cmd line: `-l INT    number of residues per line; 0 for 2^32-1 [0]`